# Pass the_post() as a parameter

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I would like to take the following code sample

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_field('title'); ?></h2>
    <p><?php the_field('desc'); ?></p>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

and convert it to use a function rather than putting all my code in my archive file. I would like to pass the the_post() as a parameter so I have access to all of the fields for a given content type.

```
function formatMyCustomPost($thePost) {
    $html = "<h2>" . get_field('title') . "</h2>";
    $html .= "<p>" . get_field('desc') . "</p>";
    return $html;
}
```

and call it like this

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <php echo formatMyCustomPost(the_post()); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried that code yet?

Comment: Yea I tried it and was able to echo out one of the values, but it seemed like something was off, since I wasn't doing anything with $thePost

Comment: You may not need to pass in `the_post()`. Calling the_post sets up the global $post object, and get_field() may also be accessing the global $post object

Comment: @czerspalace you should post your last comment as an answer :-)

Comment: I can't vote, but I agree with @PieterGoosen

Comment: @marty yes, you need 15 reputation to vote up answers, but you don't need any reputation to accept answers on your own posts :-). You can accept an answer by simply clicking on the check mark next to it just below the up/down arrows. It will go green. You also gain 2 reputation points by accepting answers to your posts :-)

Comment: Oh yea I know, I was actually about up-voting your comment @PieterGoosen!

Comment: Hahaha, misunderstood you there. Noddy badge for me :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not need to pass in `the_post()`. Calling `the_post()` sets up the global $post object, and `get_field()` may also be accessing the global $post object